# how to COPY Attribute value in a new attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, sqlxml

How to copy data of attribute to new attribute in the same column in sql

original data

```
<root>
<child attr='hello'></child>
</root>
```

Result 1

```
<root>
<child attr='hello' attr2='hello'></child>
</root>
```

Result 2(with a modification)

```
<root>
<child attr='hello' attr2='**H**ello **W**orld'></child>
</root>
```

**I want to do this only through SQL XML Xquery**

Comment: I donot want to use xslt

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow what you're wanting exactly in the second result, but I'll take a stab at it: the first example below would produce your result #1 (I've put your original data in test.xml and assumed in your real data that 'child' and 'attr' might be repeated):

```
<root>{
  for $child in doc('test.xml')/root/*
  return
    element {name($child)} {
      for $attr at $index in $child/@*
      return (
        attribute {name($attr)} {$attr},
        attribute {concat(name($attr), 2)} {$attr}
      )
    }
}</root>
```

It could be modified to put a different value in, like in result #2, like the below:

```
<root>{
  for $child in doc('test.xml')/root/*
  return
    element {name($child)} {
      for $attr at $index in $child/@*
      return (
        attribute {name($attr)} {$attr},
        attribute {concat(name($attr), 2)} {
          '**H**ello **W**orld' 
        }
      )
    }
}</root>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to do this only through SQL XML Xquery

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we can use XSLT, I would do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="attr2">
                <xsl:value-of select="@attr"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you want the modification in Result 2, replace `<xsl:template match="child">` with the following:

```
<xsl:template match="child">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="attr2">
            <xsl:value-of>
                <xsl:text>**H**ello **W**orld</xsl:text>
            </xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I want to do this only through SQL XML Xquery

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @xmlData table (
   data xml
   )


INSERT INTO @xmlData(data) 
VALUES ('<root>
   <child attr="hello"></child>
   </root>')
```

`.modify()` performs all operations

```
UPDATE @xmlData
SET data.modify('insert (attribute attr2 {"hello"}) into (/root/child)[1]')
```

Verify that the data is correct

```
SELECT *
FROM @xmlData


UPDATE @xmlData
SET data.modify('replace value of (/root/child/@attr2)[1] with "**H**ello **W**orld" ')
```

Verify that the data is correct

```
SELECT *
FROM @xmlData
```

[image]